# How to do any or two successful minion return in Saltstack orch state?

Tags: salt-stack

I tried to write some orchestration state for converting HBase to high available mode. To do so, there are couple requirements for checking:

1. Datanode process has to be up and running on `ALL` nodes.
2. HRegion process has to be up and running on `ALL` nodes.
3. After converting, namenode process has to be up and running on `two` nodes only.

So I got `ALL` implicitly for free, e.g.

```yaml
{# If all minions passed, then this will pass #}
2_1_example_pod_is_dn_running:
  salt.function:
    - name: cmd.run
    - tgt: 'G@stype:hbase and G@pod_name:example_pod'
    - tgt_type: compound
    - arg:
      - ps aux | grep datanode
    - failhard: True
```

But how to check `any` or two?

```yaml
{# Pseduo code. This won't work. #}
2_3_example_pod_is_nn_running:
    - name: cmd.run
    - tgt: 'G@stype:hbase and G@pod_name:example_pod'
    - tgt_type: compound
    - arg:
      - ps aux | grep namenode
    - successful_count: 2   {# <== namenode process has to be running on two minions #}
    - failhard: True
```

Comment: Open issue on: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/60979

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you want for this is to know which minions should "fail" the check. if you know you can use fail_minions to mark the minions that will not have namenode.

For things like this it is almost always to either be specific. when setting it up so you know how which minions will have namenode. or, to skip the check an use subset to only start namenode on 2 servers. subset will pick the number of servers of a subset of the targeted minions randomly and run the command on only the subset.